# Working with generics that contain inner generics

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I've been expanding my library of generic extension methods and have run into something I've never really considered before.  In this simple case, I have a generic `.Remove<T>` *ListExtension* that allows you to feed a `List<T>` another `List<T>` and remove all items from the first that are in the other.  Yes, I know there are other ways to do this, but I've run into it a few times in some various puzzles that I wanted to make an extension method.

That said, sometimes the value of `T` may contain another inner type, for instance `List<List<char>>()`.  In this case, the value of `T` in the method is `List<char>`.  What I'm trying to do is also capture the value of the inner `List` generically as `U`.

In this case, I'm looking at something like this:

```
public static void Remove<T>(this List<T> source, List<T> other, bool allInstances = false)
{
    if (typeof(System.Collections.ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        if (typeof(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<U>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            foreach (T item in other)
            {
                if (allInstances)
                {
                    source.RemoveAll(r => ((System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<U>)r).SequenceEqual((System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<U>)item));
                }

                else
                {
                    var v = source.Single(s => ((System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<U>)s).SequenceEqual((System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<U>)item));
                    source.Remove(v);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, for example:

```
{
  List<List<char>> source = new List<List<char>> { new List<char> { 'a', 'y', '9', '+', '~' },
                                                   new List<char> { 'b', '6', '%' },
                                                   new List<char> { '3', 'a', '?', 'P' },
                                                   new List<char> { '`', '"', '2', 'Z' },
                                                   new List<char> { '_', 'p' } };
  List<List<char>> other = new List<List<char>>  { new List<char> { 'b', '6', '%' },
                                                   new List<char> { '`', '"', '2', 'Z' } };

  source.Remove(other);
}
```

would remove the two lists in `other` from `source`.  I need to case those inner lists to `IEnumerable<U>` to access the `.SequenceEqual` LINQ method.  Again, I understand there are different approaches for this, but it's now become a problem I'd like to understand how to solve.

I've tried creating `U` in these ways (the first line was `U`, then I tried adding the second line as well, but that didn't seem to work out, either):

```
Type u = other[0].GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];//.MakeGenericType(); 
var U = Activator.CreateInstance(u);
```

So, is it possible to capture that inner generic value and actually use it as a type for casting? Especially given that there may be NO inner generic as well.  Someone had suggested making an additional method for `(this List<List<T>> source, List<List<T>> other)`, but it could be a `List<Dictionary<int, string>>` or any other, and I'd like to approach them similarly.

Comment: You are probably better off creating a separate overload `Remove<T>(this List<List<T>> source,...` and relying on overload resolution to sort it out.

Comment: Aside: Have you thought about generalizing for IEnumerable?

Comment: @Charlieface - yes, eventually it will be generalized for IEnumerable, but I'd like to get List sorted out first.  As to separate overloads, I'm trying to make this, uhh... generically generic.  Having to have an overload for a variety of inner types would get cumbersome.  As it is (though not shown) I'm also covering cases where it's a collection of arrays (e.g. - `List<char[]>`), which is similar, but slightly easier to deal with.  Of course a typical List<> of a non-collection, non-array type is easier still.  But collections of collections have been giving me a headache.

Comment: But if you use `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` that will solve the `List<char[]>` case as well. Generics do give headaches. It sounds like you have a "higher-order function" problem, not easily solved with C# generics, without using a lot of reflection